# Why does Java compiler decide whether you can call a method based on the “reference” type and not on actual “object” type?

Tags: java

I was just wondering why does Java compiler decide whether you can call a method based on the "reference" type and not on actual "object" type? To explain I would like to quote an example:

```
class A {
void methA() {
    System.out.println("Method of Class A.");
} 
}

class B extends A {
void methB() {
    System.out.println("Method of Class B.");
}
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    A ob = new B();
    ob.methB();       // Compile Time Error
}
}
```

This will produce a Compile Time Error that method `methB()` not found in `class A`, although Object Reference "ob" contains an object of `class B` which consists of method `methB()`. Reason for this is that Java Compiler checks for the method in `Class A` (the reference type) not in `Class B` (the actual object type). So, I want to know whats the reason behind this. Why does Java Compiler looks for the method in Class A why not in Class B(the actual object type)?

Comment: With the variety of ways an object could be passed around, the compiler cannot possibly know what type an object will be at a given point. If you, the programmer, know for sure, you can just cast it as appropriate. If you don't know for sure, you can use instanceof to check at any point.

Comment: Because that's the way the language is designed. AFAIK there is only one circumstance when the compiler definitely knows the object type, and it hasn't been made into a special case. If you want the compiler to know it's a B, declare it as a B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that you have an `Animal` class and a `Dog` class which *extends* `Animal`. Now, if Animal defines a method named `speak()` and Dog defines a method named `bark()`. If you do something like this :

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

It means you are pointing to a Dog and saying that it is an Animal. When you look at a Dog as an Animal (and not as a Dog), you can only call methods which are defined for an Animal, not for a Dog.

During compilation, the compiler checks if a method being called is defined in the *reference type*.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring the variable to be of type A you essentially hide the fact that it actually is a subtype. Not seeing the methods of type B is standard behavior which is essential in (strictly typed) object orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, the compiler has no idea about the type of the variable. Unlike the scenario you described above, it's usually not that obvious what the actual "object" type is. That's why the "object" type is the **runtime** type: it's known at runtime.

Imagine a method like this:

```
public static void process(A ob) {
    ob.methB(); //how do you know if this is valid?
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    process(new B()); //would make the above call valid
    process(new A()); //would make the above call invalid
}
```

Simply put, you **allow** the variable to have a runtime type that would make your call invalid. It **might** be valid, but if you rely on `methB()`, you have to take a B as parameter.

Back to your code example, this example doesn't make any sense:

```
A ob = new B();
//why would you declare ob as A if you are storing a B inside it
//this is only useful if you want to store different types of objects in it at some point
//however, that's not the case, because in the next line:
ob.methB(); //you're calling methB()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt is fine but its a one type of oops. You are assigning one sub class object to super class so i will expose only super class's method to caller.

Simply you assume that A class as interface which have 2 methods and B is implementation class which have ten methods inside it. But if you try to create object for that class with interface A it will expose only 2 methods. The same logic is applied in your case.